# mongoose result's property is undefined, but exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose

I run into strange case. This is the second time when run into this problem.
I added comment after every console.log to see the results:

```
    Spain.find()
    .limit(5)
    .exec((findErr, results) => {
        if(findErr){
            console.log('error while login', findErr);
        } else if(!results) {
            console.log('err with res');
        } else {
            let pool = 0;

            results.forEach((res, index) => {
                pool -= 1000;

                console.log(res); // {test1: 10, test2: 30, test3:20}

                let max = Math.max(res.test1, res.test2, res.test3);

                console.log(res.test1, res.test2, res.test3); // undefined undefined undefined
                console.log('max', max); // NaN
            });
        }
    });
```

Any idea, how this is possible?

UPDATE:

This code run as worker, maybe this is matter...

Node.js version: 7.10.1, mongoose version: 4.11.4

UPDATE 2: The code is within a typescript class. - Maybe parser error?

Comment: I suppose each res inside of results is an object with 3 properties: test1, test2 and test3. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right, results is an array witch contains objects and res represent one object from results.

Comment: So strange... console.log(res) gives you the object, and one line later console.log(res.test1) says such property isn't defined... Maybe a spelling mistake?

Comment: Really strange, I check the spelling so many times, and copy and paste from the database, but the same every time.

Comment: I tested with that way too :( - same result.

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint inside of your forEach function, and output here what you get after debugging? For each cycle in the forEach loop?

Comment: Use `.lean()`. This is "mongoose" and not raw "MongoDB". Mongoose models expect their properties to be defined in schema. If not then they are `undefined` ( not `null` ). And there are other ways to access as well.

Comment: what is results?

Comment: @NeilLunn You were right, the problem was the mongoose schema. In that the properties was started with uppercase e.g (Test1, Test2). Thank you for your help! If you make an answer I will accept it.